# ffmpeg split audio file into individual segments

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, mp3, splice

I have a 00:15:24 length .mp3 file that I want to split up into three separate files, ideally using a txt file input like so:

segemnts.txt

```
00:00:00 00:04:55 seg1
00:04:55 00:08:41 seg2
00:08:41 00:15:24 seg3
```

How can I do this with a single command?

Answer (score 2):

```
while read start end out; do
    ffmpeg -nostdin -y -ss "$start" -to "$end" -i my.mp3 "$out"
done < segments.txt
```

`seg1` etc must have the extension: `seg1.mp3`. Alternatively, use `"$out.mp3"` to add it in the script.

Comment: helpful [docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html):
`-nostdin`: "Disabling interaction on standard input is useful, for example, if ffmpeg is in the background process"
`-y` (global): "Overwrite output files without asking."
`-ss` position (input/output): "When used as an input option (before -i), seeks in this input file to position"